# Using same browser instance how to run the test suite

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng.xml

I'm having a testsuite(4 classes) which have common login for all classes. When I run the test suite, with first class alone having login functionality and commenting the login code for rest of the 3 classes(redirecting the url ), its running only the first class, rest of the 3 classes got failed!

```
 <classes>
 <class name="testcases.TestClass1"></class>
 <class name="testcases.TestClass2"></class>
 <class name="testcases.TestClass3"></class>
 <class name="testcases.TestClass4"></class>

</classes>
```

Please help on this

Answer (score 0):

You can try using before suite annotation available in TestNG.

@BeforeSuite: The annotated method will be run before all tests in this suite have run.

Create the driver instance as part of before suite and access it across.

Refer to [TestNG](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) documentation for more information on the annotation.

Comment: Hi supputuri, I had added common login feature in beforesuite class and extends the class in all classes. But still beforesuite class only running, rest of the classes was not running